# GL850G-SSOP28 datasheet - Ferrites values?

Tags: usb, hub

I have found a circuit for using the GL850G chip to build a powered USB 2.0 hub:

http://pdf-file.ic37.com/uploadpdf_old/GENESYS/GL850G-SSOP28_datasheet_898289/146940/GL850G-SSOP28_datasheet.pdf

However, some datas are missing. I can't see the values of the ferrites LB1 to LB6. How can I get this information ?

Comment: Ask the supplier.

Comment: That's a good way indeed :D

Answer (score 2):

There is a design for an [RPi HUB here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwj0_unSodXZAhWELMAKHeG9AfkQFghGMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ftdichip.com%2FDocuments%2FDataSheets%2FModules%2FDS_RPi_HUB_Module.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0UhGLxrTF2IftyGsOq_WTE) and that uses the same chip and has ferrite beads in several of the same places (from my quick look). The FB part on this link is described as 600R/0.5A if that's any help: -

[image]

[Here's another reference design](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwj0_unSodXZAhWELMAKHeG9AfkQFghUMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ftdichip.com%2FDocuments%2FDataSheets%2FModules%2FDS_USB_HI-SPEED_SERIAL_HUB_MODULE.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1V7Xnt8fcOz8MG8wRJSA5J) that uses the same FB: -

[image]

You can get one from [**here**](http://www.newark.com/wurth-elektronik/7427920415/ferrite-bead-600r-0-5a-0805/dp/24AC5594): -

[image]

Nothing beats getting the data from the original designer though.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Very useful answer, especially since the Hub is for a SBC ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The beads are to reduce EMI from SMPS frequency radiating between source and load.

The impedance range selection is not as wide as the frequency range , but I believe if you choose 50kHz range SMPS, then the high mu ferrite is required > 50 ohm.  The low mu ferrite is for UHF range.

You must decide based on SMPS you choose. Pick the largest for analog Vcca that fits. ( closer to 500R)

I hope you have the GL850G design guide for layout.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, I have the guide but don't read the totality. 
I have also seen a shematic without beads! http://hands.com/~lkcl/eoma/kde_tablet/gl850g_schematic.jpg

Comment: yes that would depend on source voltage ripple.  Use max XL(f)/XC(f) to guide your selection for your choice of f and ripple spectrum with low ESR bulk C.

Comment: This is more relevant than performance near USB data rate

Answer (score 1):

Ripples from SMPS are in low-MHz range, and don't radiate much over USB cables, which act as antennas. The function of ferrite bead is to reduce EMI from ripples/spikes at 30/60/240/480/720/960 MHz harmonics that result from internal operation of hub processor. They might penetrate ground and power nets when de-coupling and grounds are done poorly, and radiate badly. So the ferrites are simple countermeasures to pass FCC certification and, depending on layout quality, may be unnecessary. The rule is to get beads with highest rated impedance at minimum ampacity to meet VBUS power requirement (500 mA or 900 mA for USB3).

Best way is to make several board variants and run the design in an anechoic chamber facility, and experimentally select beads for best suppression results. You might need none, which saves on production costs.

Comment: Can a anechoic chamber be rented ? :D

Comment: Yes, on hourly or daily basis, usually with fully calibrated and certified equipment, all set for whichever FCC rules you need.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea how to design and test a simple hub !
Thanks !